# How to display a column value in "hint" property in Oracle Forms 6i?

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, oracleforms

I'm new in Oracle Forms and I would like to display in "Hint" section of my forms a value from every column comments from the table used in the forms. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use get_item_property and set_item_property to dynamically get and set the hint text from items:

> Get_Item_Property(it_id,HINT_TEXT);
>
> Set_Item_Property(it_id,HINT_TEXT,'value');

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to retrive column table comments in the following way:

```
select comments
from all_col_comments
where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'
and column_name = 'FIRST_NAME';
```

In a form trigger WHEN_NEW_ITEM_INSTANCE at form level,
you could retrive that comment according to the current item and current block.